# Emulator for MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, android, ide, emulation, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and have a question about the Emulator.

For some strange reason, half the time that I try to use the emulator, it does not work. The emulator starts up, gets to the login screen, and the IDE still shows that the emulator is offline.

Other times, it takes two or three times to get it working correctly.

Why is this? And more importantly, how can I get it working first time every time?